# What source of Halacha do Ashkenazim generally follow?

Tags: halacha

Amongst the classic sources of Halacha, like the Mishnah Berurah and the Shulchan Aruch, which one is the one that Ashkenazim (generally) follow?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Shulchan Aruch consists of the text of Rabbi Karo, who lived in Safed, with additions from Rabbi Isserles, who lived in Krakow. Once you start with Rabbi Isserles' notes, you're in firm Ashkenazic territory from there. But that's still late 1500s. And there's still a lot of room for interpretation!

Most of the popular commentaries on the Shulchan Aruch -- such as *Shach* and *Taz* on some of its sections -- reflect an Ashkenazic perspective (unless they spell out otherwise).

By the 1800s and early 1900s, you have works such as Mishnah Brurah, Kitzur Shulchan Aruch, and Chayei Adam, among many, many others. Many of these works (with notable exception the *Aruch HaShulchan*) only address some subset of the Shulchan Aruch. (For example Mishnah Brurah is on *Orach Chaim*, which addresses daily practice. If someone says *I follow the Mishnah Brurah's opinion of how to spell a given name in a divorce document* or *who is responsible when a shared business dissolves*, they are pulling your leg. Those are in sections of Shulchan Aruch without the Mishna Brurah's commentary.)

So there really isn't one all-inclusive Ashkenazic source post-Isserles.

Much of Ashkenazic *custom* cited by Isserles comes from Maharil, earning him the title of "father of Ashkenazic custom."